# Number of empty boxes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

n balls are placed into d boxes at random with all $d^n$ possibilities equally likely. Assume d>8. Let x be the number of empty boxes. Let D be the event that no box receives more than 1 ball. Let A be the event that boxes 1,2,3 and 4 are all empty, B be the event that boxes 3,4,5,6 are all empty, and C be the event that boxes 5,6,7,8 are all empty.

a) Calculate and simplify E[X].

b) Calculate and simplify Var(X).

c) Find $P(A\cup B\cup C)$.

d) If both $n,d\rightarrow\infty$ together, what relation must they satisfy in order to have $P(D)\rightarrow0.1$?

I solved parts (a), (b), and (c). My issue is with (d). I found that

$P(D)=\frac{d!}{d^{n+1}(d-n)!}$

and by using Stirling's formula I got

$P(D)\approx\frac{e^{-n}}{\sqrt{d(d-n)}}(\frac{d}{d-n})^n$

but I'm stuck here.

Comment: Look like there are pieces of missing information in your question. Can you show your working of part (a), (b) and (c) which you claimed you have solved? From your working, it is possible to find out some of these missing pieces.

Comment: By defining $X=\sum_{i=1}^dI_{A_i}$ where $A_i$ is the event that $i^{th}$ box is empty, I found $E[X]=\frac{(d-1)^n}{d^{n-1}}$, $var(X)=\frac{(d-1)^n}{d^{n-1}}-\frac{(d-1)^{2n}}{d^{2n-1}}+\frac{(d-1)(d-2)^n}{d^{n-1}}-\frac{(d-1)^{2n}}{d^{2n-1}}$. And finally by the principle of inclusion-exclusion I got $P(A\cup B\cup C)=\frac{3(d-4)^n-2(d-6)^n}{d^n}$.

Comment: There are $d^n$ possibilities, not $n^d$.